# How to stop Xcode build from shell script

Tags: xcode, bash, shell

I am currently working on an app in Xcode where I've added a Build Phase that runs a shell script.

The script looks for resources from the Desktop and copies them to the app . If the files/folders don't exist, the script should cancel the build of the app.

I have tried various things to stop the build such as `xcodebuild clean` but I can't quite figure it out. Here is what I have:

```
if [ -d ~/Desktop/MyFolder ]; then
    cp -r ~/Desktop/MyFolder ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/MyFolder
else
    #Stop the build
fi
```

Is there a way to have the script tell Xcode to stop the build? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to return a non-zero exit code from the script:

```
exit 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another useful technique is for the script to produce an output with an "error: " prefix.
This will cause Xcode to show the error within the build logs, and if you Xcode settings stop building on failure - it will stop right there.

In addition to this, you could also trigger a warning by printing out "warning: " prefix.

Example:

```
if [ -d ~/Desktop/MyFolder ]; then
    cp -r ~/Desktop/MyFolder ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}/MyFolder
else
    echo "error: Copy failed!"
fi
```

Comment: The advantage of this over the `exit 1` is that it shows the actual error in the Build time errors pane

Comment: This is great except when archiving, it doesn't cancel the task. You need to use both `exit 1` to abort archiving. For regular building, it's fine.